# How to run function once on client side in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js

In Next.js 12 I used the following approach to run a certain function once on the client side when the application loaded, e.g. to log the version number to console:

```js
// pages/_app.tsx

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  useEffect(() => console.log(`v${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERSION ?? ''}`), []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

How to do the same in Next.js 13 when using the `app` directory instead of the `pages` directory? The root layout `app/layout.tsx` is a server component so I cannot use `useEffect` there.

Answer (score 1):

One way run to achieve the same is to create a client component which is doing nothing but the logging and use that in the root layout:

```js
// app/layout.tsx, server component

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <VersionLogger>{children}</VersionLogger>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
} 


// VersionLogger.tsx, client component
'use client';

import { FC, ReactNode, useEffect } from 'react';

export const VersionLogger: FC<{ children: ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => console.log(`v${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERSION ?? ''}`), []);

  return <>{children}</>;
};
```

However I'm not sure if this has any performance implications.